# Node Application on Azure using Teamcity?

Tags: node.js, azure, teamcity, gulp, iisnode

How can I deploy Node application on Azure. I was reading [this](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/06/three-ways-of-deploying-nodejs-apps-to.html) article, however my deployment scenario is different.

My `node` applicaiton is using `git` as version control. `Gulp` as task automation. `Teamcity` as continuous integration server.

When I checkin, teamcity runs all the build steps defined using gulp, which include unit tests and creating optimised (js minify, concatenation, angular template cache etc.) build for node applicaiton. The optimised build created by Teamcity need to be deployed on Azure under [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode). Can't deploy using git push as the generated build isn't a git repository.

Anything to point in the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks